# Bootstrap dropdown not working with standard JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have no idea what I am doing when it comes to front-end development.
I have an anchor tag, and upon a click, I want a Bootstrap dropdown menu to show, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Developer Ctrls</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above HTML is taken directly from http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns

The problem is that although the anchor tag shows up, when I click it nothing happens - the dropdown menu does not appear.

*I have both bootstrap js and css, from: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/*

What is the step that I am missing in order to get the dropdown to show?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap is referenced in your code? And do you have jQuery too?

Comment: Do you include both of Bootstrap's CSS and JS files?

Comment: thanks, yeah I have jQuery and I have the latest version of bootstrap js/css from the CDN that I mentioned

Comment: I ask about Bootstrap version as the docs you link are for Bootstrap v2, not v3.

Comment: oh shit I didn't realize that

Comment: just copied your code into a page i am working on at the moment and it works for me

Comment: huh, yeah I don't know what's up, but if the HTML is right, that's a good first step for me

Comment: I think I figured it out...I was using jQuery v 3.0 beta, but I switched to jQuery 2.7 or whatever, and that worked..will delete the question, thanks for your help though!

Comment: @AlexMills if anything , you should post your own answer to the your question.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue you will need bootstrap **version 2.3.2**. To do this, take the cdn from [your link](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) and change it from this:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

... to this:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

**As commented below:**

The **BETTER** option would be to build in the newer version of bootstrap, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/70vmmrrx/2/

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Developer Ctrls
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd much rather recommend using v3 HTML instead of using old (unsupported) versions of libraries.

Comment: @DavidG I agree, however that would not answer the OP's question. That would be an alternative solution, but not the answer. right?

Comment: Well OP is using the wrong docs, so it's still a valid solution.

Comment: @DavidG lol, well kind of. I don't feel like writing the HTML to match the newer version of boostrap. But yes, I see your point.

Comment: @DavidG I stopped being lazing and updated my answer.